# Is 'the bombe' technically a computer?what is technically meant to be a computer?

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture, cryptography

Some say that 'the bombe' created by Alan Turing is technically not a computer despite decrypting the codes.

Why is it so? Is 'the bombe' technically a computer?

First of all what is technically meant to be a computer?, When even olden mechanical machines like step reconer or hollerith tabulating machine is often regarded as computer but not 'the bombe'(correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: I'm not sure there's an agreed upon meaning of computer. It's like asking whether a virus is alive.

Comment: At the very least, "computer" meant something very different today and then. "The Bombe" certainly _computed_ something, but was not a general-purpose, (conceptually) Turing-complete device we call "computer" today (iirc).